# Google Code for Lead Conversion Page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to put Google Analytics code after people signup AJAX contact form.

If I put this in PHP file that gets submitted by AJAX post request. Do you think this will trigger this javascript codes when it runs?

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you could create a results page that contains your Analytics code. On getting back results from Ajax dynamically create an iFrame that loads your results page. Set the iFrame's display attribute to none (e.g. style="display:none;").

This should have the results page show up in your Analytics stats without visitors to the site seeing it.

**Edited to add:** Google's official approach is documented here: https://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1033068

It's less of a hack than the above :-)